# Python: multiple calls to __init__() on the same instance

Tags: python, initialization

The `__init__()` function gets called when object is created.
Is it ok to call an object `__init__()` function again, after its been created?

```
instance = cls(p1=1, p2=2)
# some code
instance.__init__(p1=123, p2=234)
# some more code
instance.__init__(p1=23, p2=24)
```

why would anyone wanna call `__init__()` on an object that is already created?

good question. i wanna re-initialize the instance's fields.

Comment: This is a terrible design.  Folks trying to read and maintain your code will be baffled.  Please use ordinary methods with ordinary names.  Have `__init__` call another method (e.g., `reset`) so it's clear what's going on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798899/preferred-way-of-resetting-a-class-in-python
could be the best answer to this question. To re-initialize, you could reset it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's fine to call `__init__` more than once on an object, as long as `__init__` is coded with the effect you want to obtain (whatever that may be).  A typical case where it happens (so you'd better code `__init__` appropriately!-) is when your class's `__new__` method returns an instance of the class: that *does* cause `__init__` to be called on the returned instance (for what might be the second, or twentieth, time, if you keep "recycling" instances via your `__new__`!-).

Some additional guidance can be found here. [Multiple calls to **init** during object initialization](https://codeql.github.com/codeql-query-help/python/py-multiple-calls-to-init/)

Answer (score 6):

You can, but it's kind of breaking what `__init__` is intended to do. A lot of Python is really just convention, so you might as well follow then and expect `__init__` to only be called once. I'd recommend creating a function called `init` or `reset` or something which sets the instance variables, use that when you want to reset the instance, and have `__init__` just call `init`. This definitely looks more sane:

```
x = Pt(1,2)
x.set(3,4)
x.set(5,10)
```

Comment: +1: please do not call `__init__` It violates the expectations of everyone reading and maintaining your code.  It's simply bad design.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it does not cause any problems (*edit:* as suggested by the kosher usage of `super(...).__init__(...)`), but I think having a `reset()` method and calling it both in `__init__()` and when you need to reset would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

From my tries, I figured out it would not cause an error if you call an object `__init__` function again after it's being created. You will just reinitialize the object's attributes, and the previously defined `__init__` would be overwritten. However, it's not common and meaningful to do so. It would also confuse other people when reading your code. If you want to reset your instance, you could do so by defining a separate method or function.

Comment: What does your answer add to previous answers, in particular https://stackoverflow.com/a/2145048/12846804 ?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35347668)