# Preferred way of resetting a class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Based on [this post on CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/173505/140805).

I have a class 
`Foo` in Python (3), which of course includes a `__init__()` method. This class fires a couple of prompts and does its thing. Say I want to be able to reset `Foo` so I can start the procedure all over again.

What would be the preferred implementation?

Calling the `__init__()` method again

```
def reset(self):
    self.__init__()
```

or creating a new instance?

```
def reset(self):
    Foo()
```

I am not sure if creating a new instance of `Foo` leaves behind anything that might affect performance if `reset` is called many times. On the other hand `__init__()` might have side-effects if not all attributes are (re)defined in `__init__()`.

Is there a preferred way to do this?

Comment: "You are doing it wrong". There is no "reset class" pattern for a reason: when you are done with the data in a class instance, you dispose of that instance and create another one.

Comment: @jsbueno Which is what the second option does, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Not really - these are things to do if by some reason you'd like to have only one instance ever of your class - that is seldon needed (and if it were needed, it should be taken care of in the  `__new__` method). Just create a new instance - if there are no other references to the previous instance, it will be discarded naturally.  In other words: normal  code does not call `__init__`  "manually" - just create a new instance and allow the language do that.

Comment: I'd like to point out that "create and dispose new instance" approach sometimes results in a memory usage explosion, especially in languages like python where you have no way to clean up after yourself with a function like .Dispose() or .Free() and have to trust garbage collector. Imagine you need to create thousands, millions of that class, or just one and reuse. Not only would the memory usage differ astronomically, it would also be faster because there is no new memory allocation each time. So... please refrain from "one method covers all" lessons.

Comment: Re-initialising `self` in the reset method would be bad if you have a class variable that is changed with the init. Let us say the class keeps track of how many objects have been created with ```num``` and in ```__init__()``` you add `1` to `num`, then logically resetting isn't the same as creating.

Comment: @jsbueno I'm not sure "just create a new instance" is a convenient approach. If instantiation involves passing many parameters, then re-doing it again later in code runs the risk of not re-initializing an identical instance. Being able to call `foo.reset()` to reset all variables (but not the constant parameters) is a convenient and common use case (i.m.o.).

Comment: @Bill: it sure has uses, but it is far from the most common pattern. For a complex service with a lot of site-effects, even different kinds of 'reseting' make sense. But for simple, record-style objects, with no side-effects, creating new ones should be the rule - and of course there are tons of cases where one might want to do otherwise. In Python you may think on calling a dict's `.clear()` vs creating a new dict: just see how often each gets used in normal code.

Comment: @jsbueno If the instantiation is computationally expensive, for example when initializing a dynamic model that will be simulated over time, then a reset method makes a lot of sense. Rather than re-build the model each time you want to run a new simulation, you only reset the dynamic variables.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both are correct but the semantics are not implemented the same way.

To be able to reset an instance, I would write this (I prefere to call a custom method from `__init__` than the opposite, because `__init__` is a special method, but this is mainly a matter of taste):

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
    def reset(self):
        # set all members to their initial value
```

You use it that way:

```
Foo foo      # create an instance
...
foo.reset()  # reset it
```

Creating a new instance from scratch is in fact simpler because the class has not to implement any special method:

```
Foo foo      # create an instance
...
foo = Foo()  # make foo be a brand new Foo
```

the old instance will be garbage collected if it is not used anywhere else

Both way can be used for *normal* classes where all initialization is done in `__init__`, but the second way is required for special classes that are customized at creation time with `__new__`, for example immutable classes.

---

But beware, this code:

```
def reset(self):
    Foo()
```

will **not** do what you want: it will just create a new instance, and immediately delete it because it will go out of scope at the end of the method. Even `self = Foo()` would only set the local reference which would the same go out of scope (and the new instance destroyed) at the end of the methos.

Comment: This method is the natural solution that comes to mind first, but... Even tho it is indeed valid in python and does work, many IDE's will have trouble with code completion since they look for class members only in __init__. Just a note.

Comment: I've been using this method for a while but I think there is a problem when you have class inheritance. Suppose the child class has some additional resetting tasks to do after calling `super().reset()`. You can't add `self.reset()` to the end of the sub-class `__init__` method because then the super-class reset would be called twice. The only solution I've found is to have the `super().__init__()` call at the end of the sub-class `__init__` method, but this is not always ideal. Anyone know a better solution in this case?

Comment: I've been using a self.reset() in `__init__`, but I found today this makes `pylint` angry, specifically with `attribute-defined-outside-init` errors. It really wants `self.varname = value` in the ctor for all class variables.

Answer (score 6):

You could hold the instance you work with in a class attribute.
Whenever you want to reset the class, reassign a new instance to that attribute.
Here is how I would implement this approach:

```
class Foo:
    instance = None    # The single instance

    def __init__(self, ...):
        # Initialize the instance if Foo.instance does not exist, else fail
        if type(self).instance is None:
            # Initialization
            type(self).instance = self
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("Only one instance of 'Foo' can exist at a time")

    @classmethod
    def reset(cls):
        cls.instance = None        # First clear Foo.instance so that __init__ does not fail
        cls.instance = Foo(...)    # Now the initialization can be called
```

Then, you can access the instance by simply referring to `Foo.instance`.

I chose to have the `reset` as a class method, thus decorated by `@classmethod`.
With this decorator, the instance can be reset by calling `Foo.reset()`, and the `cls` parameter will be passed automatically to the method.

I prefer this approach (which is more or less a singleton pattern) over those you suggest, because in your situation, it appears logical to have a single instance of `Foo`, since you want to *reset* it.
Therefore, I find it rather intuitive to "force" the use of a single instance.

On the other hand, you could have an instance outside of the class, and use a `reset` instance method, defined:

```
def reset(self):
    self.__init__()
```

But this might not work so well.
Say you want to set attributes outside of the `__init__` method.
Calling `__init__` will not reset those attributes.
Therefore, your instance will not be reset as expected.
Now if you hold a single instance and reassign it to a brand new one, you're certain that it will be absolutely clean.

Regarding what you call *"creating a new instance"*, that's more or less what I chose, but the question is where to store it.
I think it makes sense to keep it warm in the class itself.

By the way, there shouldn't be any performance issue (as in "memory leak") with this solution, since only one `Foo` instance is referenced at a time, and creating a new one will de-reference the previous one.

Comment: I hadn't thought of it this way. Could you perhaps comment on why/if this is preferable to the methods I mentioned in the question?

Comment: Definitely. Thanks!

Comment: OP from the code review question, this makes a lot of sense so thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar question myself and had discovered that the best way to do it is:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.my_attribute_1 = 0
        self.my_attribute_2 = None
        self.my_attribute_3 = False
```

Now you have a `reset()` method which you can call on an instance of `MyClass` whenever you want to reset all those attributes.

However, if you have a dataclass, you need to do it like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyClass:

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.my_attribute_1 = 0
        self.my_attribute_2 = None
        self.my_attribute_3 = False
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you don't need to reset a class. But if you really want it, you can use a factory function that returns a new class for every call.

```
def make_Foo():
    class Foo():
        VALUE = 1
    return Foo

Foo = make_Foo()
Foo.VALUE = 2
print(Foo.VALUE)  # prints 2

Foo = make_Foo()  # reset
print(Foo.VALUE)  # prints 1
```