# How to properly reinitialise python object?

Tags: python

For example, I have this class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10
```

In instance lifetime, I change the value of a to 20

```
test = A()
test.a = 20
```

In which way I can properly reinitialize this instance, to make default value?

Is the way with calling __ init__ is good?

Comment: Is `test = A()` an option?

Comment: @Epic no, it should same object

Comment: Can you give a brief expanation of _why_ you want it to be the same object?

Comment: There's a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45798899/102441)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling an `__init__` would do the trick, but I wouldn't recommend it as it might be harder for other people reading your code to understand quickly what you're trying to do. I would create a `reset()` function instead:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10

    def reset(self):
        self.a = 10
```

And now,

```
test = A()
test.a = 20
test.reset() # now test.a = 10
```

---

In order to avoid code duplication, you can also call the `reset()` function from your `__init__`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.a = 10
```

Comment: I am also thinking like this but, what if logic in the init function is huge, would not it be a very big piece of duplicate code?

Comment: @IgorAlex Another approach would be to create the `reset()` function and call it in your `__init__`. In that case you won't be duplicating any code.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `__init__` is like calling a second time the constructor in another language. You may not do this.

You could create a method called `reset_variables`, that would be called in the constructor and that you would be able to call yourself.