# Factory Reset of a class instance

Tags: python, class, initialization, instance, reset

I have a Python code whose structure is as following:

```
for i in range (0,N):
    ClassInstance = A(params)
    ... #some operation that modify the attribute of the instance "ClassInstance" of the class "A"
```

`A` is a class linked to another one by a class composition relation.

Now I want to reset at each loop cycle the class' instance and:

- I don't want to create a new instance for each cycle with a different name
- I don't want to write a method in `A` for the **manual** reset of attributes since they are many and not all defined in the `__init__` method but spreaded inside the various methods of the class.

I just want that at each cycle the same old instance assumes the same state that had just after its creation; to do so I'd proceed putting a reset method in `A` like the following:

```
def reset(self, params):
    self = A(params)
```

and modify the structure of the code as follow:

```
ClassInstance = A(params)
for i in range (0,N):
    ClassInstance.reset(params)
    ... #some operation that modify the attribute of the instance "ClassInstance" of the class "A"
```

**Is it a safe way to lose track of the previous history of ClassInstance, restarting at each cycle from 0, or there is some cons that I'm not considering?**

P.S.
Searching online I saw some previous similar post (as [Preferred way of resetting a class in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798899/preferred-way-of-resetting-a-class-in-python)) but I'd like to understand if this specific way works and if I should be careful about something when proceeding by it.
Clearly if this method is a wrong way to solve my problem, other approches/solutions that fit my circumstance are well accepted as well (but in that case I'd like to understand where is the problem)

Comment: To the extent that I can understand the question at all, it seems like you're asking a subjective question about programming style - which [is off topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Hi Karl, I'd not say so; I'm not sure about the correctness of this approach, so I'm asking to better understand it. If the method is wrong surely different approaches that well fit my circumstance are well accepted as well; thank you anyway for your comment, I'll try to clarify this point in the end of my question

Comment: You'd almost certainly be better off just making a new instance. You don't need a different name. The code in your original code block works fine.

Comment: So calling the class a second time will reset all as It is the first time I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand what does the `=` operator when you assign to a variable like in `a=obj`

That does not modify the object which the variable was pointing at. That just set which object the variable will be referencing from then on, leaving the old object alone.

So `ClassInstance = A()` makes a new object and assign it to the variable `ClassInstance`

The old instance is not referenced anymore, and you cannot access it anymore. So in each loop you have a new fresh instance.

Also, you cannot reset an instance by doing `self = A()` You are assigning a new object to the local variable `self`. The instance which was referenced by `self` is not touched. Moreover, when the method returns, the self variable is released and the instance is not referenced anymore, so it is destroyed.

In general assigning to variables does not do anything. Is just like putting a label to an object. `self` is a variable like any other. There is nothing special about it.

The only way of resetting an instance is by manually setting its properties.

('object' and 'instance' in this context means the same)

By the way, you cannot in python actually destroy objects. You can delete variables with `del a` for example, but the objects are destroyed automatically when they are not referenced anymore.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the stupid question; so by making a new object at each cycle with ```ClassInstance = A(params)``` I don't have to take care of reinit the class variable since they are contained in the old instance, which is not referenced anymore; I will automatically get the same init values for the variables, right?

Comment: Yes. Each new instance is always initialized after creation.